# Let $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, and define $f_1,f_2,f_3 \in V^{*}$ as follows: $f_1(x,y,z)=x-2y$, $f_2(x,y,z)=x+y+z$, $f_x(x,y,z)=y-3z$.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

> Let $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, and define $f_1,f_2,f_3 \in V^{*}$ as follows: $f_1(x,y,z)=x-2y$, $f_2(x,y,z)=x+y+z$, $f_x(x,y,z)=y-3z$.Prove that ${f_1,f_2,f_3}$ is a basis for $V^{*}$, and then find a basis for V for which it is the dual basis.

My attempt:
Let $\beta={x_1,x_2,x_3}$ for V. To show that ${f_1,f_2,f_3}$ is a basis for $V^{*}$, it suffices to show that ${f_1,f_2,f_3}$ is linearly independent and spans $V^{*}$.

to prove that ${f_1,f_2,f_3}$ spans $V^{*}$, take any $g \in V^{*}$, and show that $g=c_1 f_1+c_2 f_2+ c_3 f_3$ for some $c_1,c_2,c_3 \in f$.

Call $h=c_1 f_1+c_2 f_2+ c_3 f_3$. we want to show h=g, so it is enough to show that $g(x_i)=h(x_i)$ for any i.

$h(x_i)=(c_1 f_1+c_2 f_2+ c_3 f_3)(x_i)=g(x_i)f_i (x_i)=g(x_i)$. So $g=h \in span {f_1,f_2,f_3}$

to prove linearly independent, it suffices to show that $c_1 f_1+c_2 f_2+ c_3 f_3=0$ and that $c_1=_2=c_3=0$.

$g(x_1)=c_1 (f_1(x_1)+ c_2 f_2(x_1)=c_3 f_3(x_1)=c_1+0+0=0$, so $c_1=0$

The same goes for $x_2$, and $x_3$, and so we have prove linearly independent.

Can someone check my work?

Comment: Since $\dim(V^*)=\dim(V)=3$, it suffices to show either that the vectors are linearly independent or that they span $V^*$. You don’t have to do both.

Comment: Your first “proof’ doesn’t really prove anything: You’ve defined both $f$ and $g$ to be identical, so of course their values are going to agree for any vector.